# Why doesn't the pop method break the while-loop in this example?

Tags: python, while-loop

Expected Outcome: while loop will break when z = []

Actual Outcome: Index Error. Loop does not break even after pop method "empties" the list.

Index error at "front_of_list = z[0]" because at that point, z = []

Example code:

```
z = [6,3,7,4,9,7,8,4,5,7]
while z:
    front_of_list = z[0]
    if z[0] == 7:
        print("SEVEN!")
        popped = z.pop(0)
    front_of_list = z[0]
    print(front_of_list)
    popped = z.pop(0)
```

Comment: it raises an index error. So you can catch it

Comment: why doesn't the while loop catch that automatically? The index error is because I'm accessing z[0] when z = []

Comment: While loops don't **continuously** test the condition; that could be arbitrarily expensive.

Comment: Thanks thats the missing link. For some reason I thought it was a continuous process.

Answer (score 2):

If you see properly and print the output:

```
z = [6,3,7,4,9,7,8,4,5,7]
while z:
    front_of_list = z[0]
    if z[0] == 7:
        print("SEVEN!")
        popped = z.pop(0)
    front_of_list = z[0]
    print(front_of_list)
    popped = z.pop(0)
    print(z)
```

This is what you get:

```
6
[3, 7, 4, 9, 7, 8, 4, 5, 7]
3
[7, 4, 9, 7, 8, 4, 5, 7]
SEVEN!
4
[9, 7, 8, 4, 5, 7]
9
[7, 8, 4, 5, 7]
SEVEN!
8
[4, 5, 7]
4
[5, 7]
5
[7]
SEVEN!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../your file", line 7, in <module>
    front_of_list = z[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Your while loop doesn't catch that because you pop the element in the `if` statement but you also pop the element outside it.

```
front_of_list = z[0]
print(front_of_list)
popped = z.pop(0)
print(z)
```

So before the iteration has completed, you pop the element. Your last element is 7 and you pop that in your if statement. Now the list is empty. But you try to pop it again outside the `if` statement. That is the error.

Example of last iteration:

```
while z:
    front_of_list = z[0] #=== last element is 7
    if z[0] == 7:
        print("SEVEN!") #=== Yes
        popped = z.pop(0) #=== 7 is removed from the list. So list is []
    front_of_list = z[0] #=== No element is in the list so you cannot index it. Hence an IndexError
    print(front_of_list)
    popped = z.pop(0)
    print(z)
```

Comment: So the while loop won't break if the list is emptied from within an if statement? The while loop can't "see" that the list is empty from inside a block like that?

Comment: okay I get it now. "while" doesn't "check" the condition continuously. Thanks for your replies sujay, appreciated!

Comment: Most welcome @dv151 consider up-voting and accepting the answer ```:-)```